# flann index saving in python

Tags: python, surf, flann

I want use flann as k-tree for surf descriptor in python. In this case I need save my flann index witch I couldn't fund any useful tutorial to guide me. Can any one help me, I new in programming!

Answer (score 4):

Agree that python docs could be better for flann but I found it reasonably easy to navigate using autocomplete in my IDE. (Have you tried wingIDE)?
Hope the following code sample gets you going in any case:

```
flannParams = { "memory_weight" : 0 , "target_precision" : 0.9999 , "sample_fraction" : 0.3 , "algorithm" : 255 , "build_weight" : 0.01}
flann = pyflann.FLANN()
flann.build_index(X,**flannParams)
flann.save_index(outputFilename)
```